# Prevent downloaded files from replacing or overwriting each other

Tags: java, mysql, swing

How to download all file types in MySQL database using Java app and prevent one file from replacing the other?

How can I include all file types in my `filepath=("D:\\sch work\\skirt\\filename.pdf");` so that I am  able to download pdf, docx, jpeg etc, from a MySQL database using Java mouse click event on a `JTable`?

I have two problems.

1. I can only open a PDF files although I want to open docs, JPEG and img files.
2. Every time I download another file from a different row it replaces the existing one. I would like to keep all of them

Below please find my code for mouse click event and please suggest what I should add for it to work as I need it.

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     


    String filePath =("D:\\sch work\\skirt\\filename.pdf");
      int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

      try {
    int cert_code= jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    String tableClick=(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(cert_code,3).toString());

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_certificate","root","");
         String sql= "SELECT cert FROM certificate WHERE cert_code =?" ;
             PreparedStatement pstmt =  con.prepareStatement(sql);

  pstmt.setString(1, tableClick); 
  ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()){
        Blob blob = rs.getBlob("cert");  
        InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
           inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
             //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"file saved")
} }
  catch (Exception e)
    {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);}  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something other than PDF, you should store what's in that cert blob, so you can send out the appropriate filename/type:

You get PDF because that's the exact+only file type you write out to:

```
String filePath =("D:\\sch work\\skirt\\filename.pdf");
                                                 ^^^
```

Perhaps something more like (in pseudo-code):

```
select cert,filename,filetype from ...
filepath = 'd:\sch work\skirt' + filename
header('Content-type: ' + filetype);
```

Comment: Hi Marc B.  The database contains images pdf and docs.all  stored as blob. Since it is so hard to tell which file is pdf and which one is not, i want to include everything in the filepath so that i can  save the file with an appropriate extension.

Comment: then you need to store extra data with the blob to identify what's in the blob, exactly as I showed above. a blob is just "binary large object". what you stuff into it is what comes out again later. it's up to YOU to provide meaning to that binary data. it's not the DB's job to go "oh, this is a pdf" or "oh, this is a jpeg". it's job is to go "oh, this is some random collection of binary garbage that I can't modify in any way".

Comment: but i think that would mean having a different mouse click events for each file type.i want to include all of them in one mouse click event.

Comment: what good would it be to have a "jpg" button, if you have a pdf in your database?

Comment: Indeed no need and that's why I need to add something to my pathfile.I have deleted all files in the database and added new ones but the problem still remain....I don't know what to add to my filepath to catch all file types so that every time I download any file I don't have to change the content of the filepath.

Comment: exactly. so add a filetype/filename field to your certs db, so you can store exactly what each cert file's name+type is, then you don't need to do any figuring out later on. you just go `downloaddir + namefromdb` and off you go.

Comment: Hi Marc B, Please help. the file downloaded is now called null. I think it is because i have initialized file_name to null.how do i resolve it?            String file_name=null:                                          select cert,file_name from ...
filepath = 'd:\sch work\skirt' + file_name

Comment: is there a filename in the db?

Comment: Yes I have added  the field

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer.God bless Marc B abundantly.

private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

```
      int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

      try {
    int cert_code= jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    String tableClick=(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(cert_code,3).toString());

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_certificate","root","");
         String sql= "SELECT cert, cert_name FROM certificate WHERE cert_code =?" ;
             PreparedStatement pstmt =  con.prepareStatement(sql);

  pstmt.setString(1, tableClick);
  ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()){
     String filename = rs.getString("cert_name");
    Blob blob = rs.getBlob("cert"); 
        InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();   
            String filePath ="D:\\sch work\\skirt\\"+filename;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
           inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
             //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"file saved")
} }
  catch (Exception e)
    {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);}  
}
```